# Adding IntelliSense for styled components theme

Tags: typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

I am trying to add IntelliSense when I am using a theme in styled components.

This is my `index.tsx` file where I use `ThemeProvider`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import App from './App';
import { GlobalStyle } from './style/globalStyle';
import { theme } from './theme/theme';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement,
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
      <GlobalStyle />
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

If it is relevant, I also have a `theme.d.ts` file:

```
// import original module declarations
import 'styled-components';
import { theme } from './theme';

// and extend them!
declare module 'styled-components' {
  export type Theme = typeof theme;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

So far, I haven't managed to have IntelliSense recognize elements in my theme. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

### Solution

Based on [this](https://dev.to/rajuashok/create-styled-d-ts-to-make-typescript-work-with-styled-components-5dk4) article I have changed theme.ts from

```
export const theme = {...}
```

To

```
export type Theme = typeof theme;

const theme = {...}

export default theme;
```

Also, I have changed theme.d.ts To

```
// import original module declarations
import 'styled-components';
import { Theme } from './theme';

// and extend them!
declare module 'styled-components' {
 // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
 export interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

And it fixed my IntelliSense issue, still not sure why

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve. Styled-components already have a DefaultTheme interface (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/models/ThemeProvider.tsx) 
Are you trying to override some properties or create your own default scheme from scratch?

Comment: Just when I use theme in a styled component I want to see intellisense for all the values like colors I have in the theme. 

 I think now it doesn't show anything  because the theme has type any

Comment: For colors you can create a file like colors.ts an in that one have something like const colors = {  light_color:  '#FFD92E' ...}
Does this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Your module augmentation should work fine (even though there should not even need to import the original module).

Styled-components documentation > TypeScript > [theme](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#create-a-declarations-file)

Your code sample differs from the above docs, as it creates the `DefaultTheme` interface from the actual `theme` value, but it works fine as well:
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwDkSaWAtAMYGQB26tMCRA3AFBvW1JwwAW6EOjgBeOAG82cONVTQEALglTpiMOkrAAhqiUAiKFj0qAvmzNtMG1FsNwQETAFcMxUhkxUaEeo2bLpdAAPSFheZHU4ABUBIVFw9QgcXlj0dkCQ6HhgRnQoHC1KYQARdAKXGBjBYWCYBkwEaNSJODMLLh4AWWQAYW9feDF3LAA6TGAANwADFVloJQAScTB8MEaRAD44FYg1kf5qkbmoBBGEdU0dE3S4AHpb1Uen55fX6QA9AH42KfYgA)

But make sure you explicitly `import` your `theme.d.ts` file: because it `import`s some other files, it is not an "ambient script", and it must be imported before it takes effect.